# wordpress comment form styling

Tags: wordpress

I have integrated a HTML Template into Wordpress theme. In, menu area there is a menu called Blog. On click of that menu I want to show all the posts. On clicking some particular posts title one should go to the single post`s page. On that page there should be comments shown which are being posted earlier by some one as well as the comment form through which one can comment on that post.

Below is my blog.php code

```
    <?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
        <div id="inner_contant">
            <div id="all_post">
                <?php
                    $myposts = get_posts('');
                    foreach($myposts as $post) :
                    setup_postdata($post);
                ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <div class="author">Posted by <?php the_author(); ?></div>
                <div class="post_excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Below is my single.php code

```
    <?php
/*
* The template for displaying all single posts and attachments
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="single_post_wrap">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <div class="time_and_author"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author() ?></div>
    <div class="post_content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    <p>Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments »', '1 Comment »', '% Comments »'); ?></p>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        <?php  foreach (get_comments() as $comment): ?>
        <div><?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?> said: "<?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?>".</div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php comments_template(); ?>    
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Below is my comments.php code

```
    <?php $comment_args = array(
            'comment_notes_after' => '',
            'title_reply' => 'Have something to say?'
        ) ?>
<?php comment_form($comment_args); ?>
```

I want to add some styling to that comment form. I have tried every thing but not worked for me. Thanks in advance for those who will help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress' [comment_form function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) prints a form with id 'commentform'. So you can use CSS to style this form.

```
form#commentform {
    // your styles.
}

form#commentform input {
    // your styles for inputs
}

/* default class of submit button is 'submit'. For changing it: add a
* key=>value to comment_form args like 
* 'class_submit' => 'your_submit_class'
*/
form#commentform .submit {
    // your submit button styles.
}
```

Also, you can change ID of comment form like this:

```
<?php $comment_args = array(
    'comment_notes_after' => '',
    'title_reply' => 'Have something to say?',
    'id_form' => 'myAwesomeCommentForm'
) ?>
<?php comment_form($comment_args); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @mht. I have been trying the whole day for this. This helps me a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for unnecessary dispute, but why I can't see the green tick?

Comment: Thanks @mht. I`m new to stackoverflow. So, It take some time to be familiar with it.